Get a screenshot / scan of a component in React
Im trying to take a screenshot of the first page of a document in a component Im using called Syncfusion.
Im reaching javascript, react and syncfusion people to ask if that is possible.
thank you

please provide revelant code and what've you tried, people can't just guess it out of nothing.

You can use html2canvas, or use mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia to get the screen stream, and then draw the stream onto a canvas.
